# Timeseries database with multi-column aggregation

Tags: database, time-series, amazon-rds, druid, riak-ts

I am trying to design a system that has time-series data. Here are the requirements of the system:

- Data comes into the system anytime of the day from multiple cities and departments.
- These individual records should be available for life-time. (optional)
- Most of the queries are aggregations. However, they happen on multiple columns. Example queries:

  - Sum of all measurements on a particular day in a particular city
  - Sum of all measurements in a (last) month in a department
  - Sum of all measurements in a (last) week in a city for a department
  - Sum of all measurements on a particular day in a state (State will also be part of the record)
- All queries should be computed with a very low latency (< 300-500 ms)

Here are the constraints I have:

- I went through multiple time-series databases. From my understanding all of them require expensive hardware. I would like to know if there is a way we can run it on commodity hardware.
- I am not sure how much data will be available at the beginning. Ideally it would be around 100 MB at peak(per day). So, I am not willing to spend hundreds of dollars at the beginning.
- Another idea I have been thinking about is to have an Amazon RDS instance and have multiple indexes on various columns and aggregate them as needed. I am not sure if this is a good idea though.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Akumuli (warning: I'm the author).
Akumuli can perform aggregations pretty quickly (sub millisecond) because it's a column-oriented database and it precomputes some aggregates for you. And it can perform all the queries that you need, e.g. if your series looks like this:

```
${measurement_name} city=${city_name} dept=${department_name} state=${state_name}
```

And the actual data looks like this (e.g this is a power consumption data measured in watts):

```
W city=Jersey_City state=New-Jersey dept=1
W city=Jersey_City state=New-Jersey dept=2
W city=Paris state=Iowa dept=1
W city=Paris state=Iowa dept=2
W city=Texas state=Texas dept=1
W city=Texas state=Texas dept=3
W city=Paris state=Arkansas dept=1
W city=Paris state=Arkansas dept=2
```

You can aggregate all data with `dept=1` and `dept=2` tags using this query:

```
{
    "aggregate": { "W": "sum" },
    "range": { "from": "20170501T000000",
               "to": "20170502T000000" },
    "group-by": [ "dept" ],
    "where": { "dept": [1, 2] }
}
```

You will get the sum for each dept but only departments 1 and 2 will be included.

You can split by the city instead:

```
{
    "aggregate": { "W": "sum" },
    "range": { "from": "20170501T000000",
               "to": "20170502T000000" },
    "group-by": [ "city" ],
}
```

You will get sum for every city name (all departments in one city will be joined). Of cause, you can filter by tag using `where` clause.

If you have several cities with the same name (e.g. Paris in Iowa and Arkansas) you can group values by city and state:

```
{
    "aggregate": { "W": "sum" },
    "range": { "from": "20170501T000000",
               "to": "20170502T000000" },
    "group-by": [ "city", "state" ],
}
```

You will get one value for Paris Arkansas and another for Paris Iowa.

Answer (score 0):

The aggregations you outlined are rather standard. It would be hard to find a database that wouldn't support them.

You could try [Axibase TSD](https://axibase.com/docs/atsd/). It can efficiently calculate calendar aggregates (e.g. daily totals) with multiple dimensions in the user-defined timezone. This would be useful if the metrics you're collecting are driven by end-user activity:

```
SELECT date_format(time, "yyyy-MMM-dd", "US/Eastern"), 
  entity AS 'city', SUM(value)
FROM "email.active_sessions"
  WHERE datetime >= current_year
  AND entity.tags.state = 'PA'
GROUP BY entity, PERIOD(1 DAY, "US/Eastern")
```

The intervals can be conveniently specified with extended keywords/functions. Here's how '(last) week' condition looks like:

```
WHERE datetime >= previous_week AND datetime < current_week
```

Refer to [SQL docs](https://axibase.com/docs/atsd/sql/) for additional examples.

ATSD runs on most Linux distributions and can be executed in both stand-along and distributed modes.

Disclosure: I work for Axibase.